# python regex [newbie]

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> my_words = 'ABC 123 456 www'
>>> my_words
'ABC 123 456 www'

>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r'\d{3}')
>>> p.findall(my_words)
['123', '456']
```

how to write the rule for compile if I want to get 13 and 46 ?

Comment: There is no 13 or 46 in your input. Are you asking how to remove the middle digit from your output? That's not something you can do with regex.

Comment: By saying that you want to get '13 and '46' as well, do you mean that you want it to work for strings like 'ABC 13' or that you want to remove the middle digit?

Comment: wow..  you guys are very enthusiastic ! I want to remove the middle digit in list if match 3-digit long string, thanks for help ᴀʀᴍᴀɴ Olivier Melançon and Mureinik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, I wouldn't use regex for this. A simple list comprehension should do the trick, and from there you could extract the first and last characters:

```
result = [w[0] + w[-1] for w in my_words.split() if len(w) == 3 and w.isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to extend your solution to work with numbers of any length, then you can accomplish this without regexp using the method `str.isdigit` that checks if a string is composed only of digits.

```
my_words = 'ABC 123 456 www 13 46'
numbers = [word for word in my_words.split() if word.isdigit()]
numbers  # ['123', '456', '13', '46']
```

If what you want is to remove the middle digit out of numbers, then you can do it with `re` by using capturing groups.

```
my_words = 'ABC 123 456 www'
numbers = list(map(''.join, re.findall(r'(\d)\d(\d)', my_words)))
numbers # ['13', '46']
```

Comment: map(''.join,re.findall(r'(\d)\d(\d)',my_words))
this is what I want,thank you !

Comment: @3h1Nh7YX24 is your number always going to be 3 digits? If so, Mureinik answer is the best approach